# How do I Promisify an Async operation, using the Async library?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, bluebird

```
GrabRedisDataByArray = Promise.promisify(function(data, callback) {
    var temp_results = [];

    async.each(data, function(result, done) {

        redis.hgetall('username:' + result, function(err, results) {

            temp_results.push(results);
            done();
        })

    }, function(err) {
        callback(temp_results)
    });

});
```

Except, it's returning

`Unhandled rejection (<[{"server":"9300","user_id":"31","char...>, no stack trace )`

--That object data is just some user information stored in the `username:` key.

---

And my method for data retrieval is:

```
 GrabRedisDataByArray(data).then(function(data){
         console.log(data)                               
 });
```

I think my problem is with `GrabRedisDataByArray` and how it doesn't return anything in the main function scope, but only returns something through its second parameter? If that makes sense? I'm just kind of lost here and trying to understand how I can return that async operation to the main function instead of only returning it through the second parameter callback (Which is I think my promises isn't working correctly)

Edit: This is using the [Bluebird library](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird)

Comment: Do you use native Promises or Bluebird or something else?

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention, yeah Bluebird

Comment: I really wouldn't try to promisify async. I'd rewrite my code to use promises.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `promisify` expects node-style callbacks, so when you're calling `callback(temp_results)` you *are* passing an error parameter. It would have to be `callback(null, temp_results)`.

---

That said, you should not use the `async` library at all when you're working with promises anyway. Just embrace promises. Or if you insist on using `async`, at least do it properly:

```
var grabRedisDataByArray = Promise.promisify(function(data, callback) {
    async.map(data, function(result, done) {
        redis.hgetall('username:' + result, done);
    }, callback);
});
```

But when promisifying, you should always promisify on the lowest level - in your case `redis`. Then you don't have to mess around with `async` callbacks but can simply use Bluebird's [`Promise.map`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html):

```
Promise.promisifyAll(redis);
function grabRedisDataByArray(data) {
    return Promise.map(data, function(result) {
        return redis.asyncHgetall('username:' + result);
    });
}
```

Comment: Where can one find more about the "always promisify on the lowest level"? I'd like a place to send people instead of arguing it myself.

Comment: @ThomasJensen I think I never gave an explanation of why you should do this :-/

Comment: Do you know if someone else did? Well, if not, here's a call for doing so. I'll be happy to sponsor it. I think there's a bunch of other promise-related best practices worth covering as well. Promises are some of the most misunderstood.

Comment: @ThomasJensen I'll add it to my todo list :-)

Comment: I feared so  I have a stub in a Google Docs with a couple other things. Feel free to e-mail me if I should share it. Cheers.